# Binary Tree Will Not Compile: Error 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list, binary-tree, codeblocks

I am in the process of creating a Binary Tree using a linked list, below i have my class funtree:

```
template <typename T>
class funtree
{
private:
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
Node* GetNewNode(T data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;

}
Node* Insert(Node* root, T data)
{
    if(root == NULL) //empty tree
    {
        root = GetNewNode(data);
        return root;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    return root;
}
bool Search(Node* root, int data)
{
   if(root == NULL)
        return false;
   else if (root->data == data)
    return true;
   else if (data <= root->data)
    return Search(root->left, data);
   else
    return Search(root->right, data);
```

and my main method:

```
 T main()
{
    Node* root; // pointer to root node
    root = NULL; // setting tree as empty
    Insert(root,15);
    Insert(root,10);
    Insert(root,20);
    T num;
    cout<<"Enter number to be searched\n";
    cin>>num;
    if(Search(root, num) == true)
        cout<<"Found\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found\n";
}
```

I am trying to test my Search Method to see if it works and when i try to compile I only get the error:

```
main.c||undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|
```

The program is also a console application and they are both in the same class, i don't think these are problems but just in case it needs to be known.

EDIT:

I have changed some parts of the code but will paste it as it looks in my compiler instead of separating the main function and the class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class funtree
{
private:
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
Node* GetNewNode(T data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;

}
Node* Insert(Node* root, T data)
{
    if(root == NULL) //empty tree
    {
        root = GetNewNode(data);
        return root;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    return root;
}
bool Search(Node* root, int data)
{
   if(root == NULL)
        return false;
   else if (root->data == data)
    return true;
   else if (data <= root->data)
    return Search(root->left, data);
   else
    return Search(root->right, data);

}

  int main()
    {
    Node* root; // pointer to root node
    root = NULL; // setting tree as empty
    Insert(root,15);
    Insert(root,10);
    Insert(root,20);
    T number;
    cout<<"Enter number to be searched\n";
    cin>>number;
    if(Search(root, number) == true)
        cout<<"Found\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found\n";
    }
```

Comment: I think it should be int main(),instead of T main()

Comment: @michaeltang well my class funtree uses a template so wouldn't my main method have to follow that?

Comment: yes, always return int in main()

Comment: @michaeltang when i do that i get:

`C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CSProjects\treefun\main.cpp||In member function int funtree<T>::main()':|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is lot of problem in your code, hope this piece of code helps

prob1: declear struct Node as private , but trying to access it in main

prob2: root* as parameter is changed when you new a node, but you didn't return the new root. either define Insert as `Node* Insert(Node*& root, T data)` or assigned the return value of function to root will be ok.

prob3: main should always return int

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class funtree
{
public:
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
Node* GetNewNode(T data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;

}
Node* Insert(Node* root, T data)
{
    if(root == NULL) //empty tree
    {
        root = GetNewNode(data);
        return root;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    return root;
}
bool Search(Node* root, int data)
{
   if(root == NULL)
        return false;
   else if (root->data == data)
    return true;
   else if (data <= root->data)
    return Search(root->left, data);
   else
    return Search(root->right, data);
}
};
int main()
{
    funtree<int> tree;
    funtree<int>::Node* root; // pointer to root node
    root = NULL; // setting tree as empty
    root = tree.Insert(root,15);
    root = tree.Insert(root,10);
    root = tree.Insert(root,20);
    int num;
    cout<<"Enter number to be seared\n";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<num;
    if(tree.Search(root, num) == true)
        cout<<"Found\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when i make these changes i get the exact same error, would you think that was just a compiler error?

Comment: @user3358064, are you trying to create a windows application? if yes,may be you should change it to a console application

Comment: it is a console application but i'll make it all over again just to make sure

Comment: @user3358064, I try to compile this code here, http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php, it works

Comment: @user3358064 try to check the code,it seems you are missing one of }

Comment: Thank you i looked over some of the edits you made when my main function started to insert and just now edited my code as well

Comment: if i could ask you one more question, i tried making an edit in your main function from `funtree<int> tree;` to `funtree<T> tree;` so it would support characters like A and B but it says `T undeclared`

Answer (score 0):

change `T main()` to `int main()`...this should remove the error.... main() always returns int...

Comment: in the comments i showed an error that i got there that says `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\CSProjects\treefun\main.cpp||In member function int funtree<T>::main()':|`

Comment: main() is global function not the part of your class..declare it as global and change your code accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be putting your main method into a template class. That cannot work. You need your main to be a non-member function. It returns `int` and is typically either:

```
int main();
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

You might need to change your compilation also because when the linker expects `WinMain` that usually indicates it is building a GUI program. But your code appears to be a console program.